# How can I check to see if a date from a csv is more than 24hours old?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, csv

I have a small program that I'm working on and I'm having trouble figuring it out.
Given that I have this setup in a csv, how can I check to see if the dates are more than 24 hours old?

**CSV sample**

> ```
> Date,Online Status,Username,User Email,Computer ID
> 2015-05-25,Online,user1,user@example.com,Computer-1
> 2015-05-25,Online,user2,user@example.com,Computer-2
> 2015-03-24,Offline,user3,user@example.com,Computer-3
> 2015-04-17,Offline,user4,user@example.com,Computer-4
> 2015-05-25,Online,user5,user@example.com,Computer-5
> 2015-05-25,Online,user6,user@example.com,Computer-6
> 2015-05-25,Online,user7,user@example.com,Computer-7
> 2015-05-25,Online,user8,user@example.com,Computer-8
> 2015-05-25,Online,user9,user@example.com,Computer-9
> 2015-05-25,Online,user10,user@example.com,Computer-10
> ```

What I have so far is this. While it's a good start (I think) I'm not able to do the math I need to get the results I need. Those results are, what computers have been online within the last 24 hours.

**Code so far**

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import logging

DAY = timedelta(seconds=86399)
FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"
TODAY = datetime.now().date()
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def csv_dict_reader(file_obj):
    """
    Read a CSV file using csv.DictReader
    :param file_obj:
    :return: info from the CSV log file
    """

    reader = csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=',')

    for line in reader:
        line["Date"] = datetime.date((line["Date"]))
        if (line["Date"] - TODAY) > DAY:
            print "Skipped"
        else:
            print datetime.datetime.strptime(line["Date"], FORMAT)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("ComputerLog.csv",) as f_obj:
        csv_dict_reader(f_obj)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot know exactly when 24hrs have passed, because you only know the date. The one thing you can only check is if someone is _at least_ 24 hours offline

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the date that is in this file represents the last log on date. The Status field represents the current status. So with the last login date I feel that there's got to be a way to find if the user or the computer has been online in the last day.

Comment: Yes you're right, but that is not the same as checking whether a user has been online for the last 24 hours.

Comment: Again sorry if my words are confusing. The base of this is to see if the computer was logged in within the last day. The user doesn't matter that much. Sorry if I am not being clear and thanks for your help.